# save output of awk into a variable in a shell script

Tags: shell, variables, awk, split

I need to save the output of this command into a variable

```
$scriptName | awk '{split($0,a,"_"); print a[1]}'
```

I tried to do this but it didn't work

```
schema=$( $scriptName | awk '{split($0,a,"_"); print a[1]}' )
```

can please someone tell me out to do that? thank you.

Comment: The awk part could be simplified as: `awk -v FS="_" '{ print $1 }'`

Comment: 1. we don't know what the output of $scriptname is , 2. you don't include any error messages or examples of what you mean by 'but it didnt work'. Please edit your question to include this information. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a slightly simpler way:

```
schema=`echo $scriptName |awk -F_ '{print $1}'`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
schema="$( $scriptName | awk '{split($0,a,"_"); print a[1]}' )"
```

(with quotes). But how do you check if it works or not?

Comment: In bash it's not strictly necessary to quote the RHS of a variable assignment. See [Simple Command Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Simple-Command-Expansion) #4 -- word splitting is not one of the actions taken on the text following the `=`.

Comment: @glennjackman, thought so. That's why I asked about the check. I suspect maybe quotes are missing there.

Answer (score 0):

Third alternative:

```
$script | awk ' ... ' | read schema
```